# Psql shell doesn't give my any confirmations when executing operations

Tags: postgresql, command-line, terminal

I installed PostgresSQL in my machine following their website's tutorial. I quickly noticed that my commands aren't being executed, and no outputs are showed to me

***Commands I tried to execute***

I tried to create a new datbase by using `CREATE DATABASE testdb` in my psql shell, and when I type `\l` the db isn't there.

I tried to create a password for the default user postgres using the command

```
postgres=# ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'postgres';
ALTER ROLE ---> Does not show for me
```

I also tried to execute the command `su - postgres` in order to create databases in my default terminal using just `createdb name-here`, but a password is required and typing postgres doesn't work (I configured the ALTER USER password to it.)

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, because it's my first time using it. Can I get some help?

Comment: Reading the docs goes a long way to understanding. For [ALTER ROLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterrole.html), `'ALTER USER` is deprecated FYI. See EXAMPLES section; `ALTER ROLE postgres WITH PASSWORD 'some_pwd';` You need the `WITH`. I do not see  ';' ending your `CREATE DATABASE` statement, in which case the statement will not complete.

Comment: I'd bet some money that you forgot the semicolon.